I want to know how manage cors in laravel 11 without config/cors.php file but with middleware and bootstrap/app.php?
I want to manage CORS in Laravel 11 using middleware and bootstrap/app.php, without relying on the config/cors.php file.
When I fetch data from my website, the response always allows all origins (*), despite my configuration to allow only http://localhost:8.
Here's my fetch request:
const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/demo");
const p = await response.json();
console.log(p);

Here is my middleware located at App/Http/Middleware/Cors.php:
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class Cors
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response)  $next
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        $response = $next($request);
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8');
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin, Authorization');

        return $response;
    }
}

And here is my bootstrap/app.php configuration:
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Exceptions;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Middleware;

return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
    ->withRouting(
        web: __DIR__.'/../routes/web.php',
        api: __DIR__.'/../routes/api.php',
        commands: __DIR__.'/../routes/console.php',
        health: '/up',
    )
    ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
        $middleware->append(\App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class);
    })
    ->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
        //
    })->create();

Despite this setup, the allowed origin remains *. How can I correctly configure CORS in Laravel 11 using middleware and bootstrap/app.php to restrict it to http://localhost:8?

which route file you are using i.e web.php or api.php? depending on that you need to append middleware to the specific route file.

Just publish cors config: https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/routing#cors
